# How authentic is Osho's Book of secrets on Vijnana Bhairava Tantra?

Tags: tantra, shaivism, meditation, kashmiri-shaivism

**First of all this is not an opinion based question, it is a factual, scriptural based question.**

---

Osho has translated(?) and delivered a set of lengthy discourses on Vijnana Bhairava Tantra which is compiled to a book called [Book of secrets](https://allbooksworld.com/the-book-of-secrets-by-osho-pdf-download/).

The famous, Swami Laxman Joo has also written two books on it called [Vijnana Bhairava: The practice of centering Awareness](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.gianfrancobertagni.it/materiali/tantra/joo2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjyxsuRt471AhU_SmwGHZ9FDu8QFnoECCEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0SX3iv-ZdtxjURpCjcqpRQ) and [Manual of Self Realisation](https://archive.org/details/the-manual-for-self-realization-112-meditations-of-the-vijnana-bhairava-tantra/mode/2up)

Now the methods, for first two or three seems to be similar but then on from the fifth method seems to be completely different. Did Osho rearrange the methods  or did he give totally new set of practices other than the classical ones?

---

Book of Secrets by Osho, List of meditations

[image]

---

Compare this with the meditations offered  in the book translated by Swami Laxman Joo. Why are the Dharans or Meditations different?

Comment: See Swami ji was last authentic Guru in KS sampradaya whereas Osho wasn't from KS. So we should always consider Swamiji works as authentic.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Yes yes, but as authentic as he is, his explanation is very standard and filled with esoteric terms and hard to understand for people who are not well versed in Kashmiri Shaivism. Where as Osho's version is beginner friendly, modern simple language with good analogies meant for the layman. So It is very good for beginner.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto and I also agree that Swamiji's version is authentic as it has Sanskrit verses and is same as other translations. So all the translations are one side and Osho's translation is on one side. I'm not questioning Swamiji's book's authenticity, that is a given. I'm questioning Osho's book's authenticity by comparing it, whether it gives the same list of meditations or not is my question.

Comment: Don't use bounties to prevent questions from getting closed

Comment: @TheDestroyer I'm not. I'm using it to attract attention. Stop assuming stuff you don't know.

Comment: @TheDestroyer why did you close the bounty?? Under your own assumption?? You are abusing your privilege.

Comment: @MrGreenGold it's been observed you apply bounties to questions with close votes to prevent them from getting closed. I even warned you once if you remember.  Check [this question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/3500).

Comment: This question is clearly opinion based since different Sampradayic followers perceive a Swami or philosopher differently. An Advaitin will have one view on Nimbarka's opinions  than Vaishnava. Asking questions like, "Are Nimbarka's views Authentic?"  is clearly opinion based. Your question falls in  this category.

Comment: @TheDestroyer nothing has been observed, any body who follows me knows that I keep giving bounties to almost all my quesitons. If some of them has few votes to close, I can't help that. I have offered bounties to so many questions with no votes, why don't you see that. Nothing has "observed" by you. All it matters is whether the question is closed or not at the time of bounty.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I'm trying to maintain my cool and humility but you are testing my patience. I have told here again and again that this is not opinion based as I'm not asking the interpretation but the order and the methods given is same as in Sanskrit or not. If some one asks whether the order of methods and the method content is same or not, it's not a opinion based question. And if anything is opinion based its your observation which says I'm putting bounty for stopping the closure of the question. Please know your place.

Comment: @TheDestroyer you are comparing this view with whether a particular philosophy is authentic? Did you read the question. It seems like you have no clue. If I ask whether a philosophy is authentic then it's different, but if I ask a particular translation is correct or if the order of the methods are same then it is not. Authentic can very different meanings

Comment: @MrGreenGold Then you should make it clear if structure of translation/explanation is same as original scriptures instead of asking vaguely if Osho's book is authentic. Make it clear you mean structure not meaning. Also, edit and flag this question instead of posting new question. Remove ambiguous portions.

Comment: @TheDestroyer it was very very clear, only if you have had the patience to slowly read the question